Python nested for loop in range
I'm new to Python with very limited previous coding experience, and I am taking Google's Crash Course on Python to learn more. I am working on an exercise problem. I know what the answer is supposed to be, but I don't know how to get there.
The answer should be:
3, 2, 1
3, 2, 1

This is the code I'm supposed to fix to get that answer:
for i in range(1, 3):
  for j in range(1, 3):
    if j != 0:    
       print(str(i) + ", " + str(j))
    else:
       print(str(j) + str(j), end=" ")

The instructions hint that I'm supposed to deprecate something in the "for j in range(1, 3)" expression.
I have tried editing this:
for i in range(1, 3):

to
for i in range(3, 3+1)

which limits the i output to 3. I am getting:
3, 1
3, 2


For starters, j will never equal 0 in that code. Whether that means the check is unnecessary or the range of values that j iterates over is wrong is at least part of what you need to consider.

Second: both loops start at 0 and count up, which should be an issue of the output is supposed to print numbers in decreasing order.

Third: the code only produces 4 total calls to print, not 6 that the output implies.

(Basically, there are quite a few things wrong with that code; it would frankly seem easier to rewrite it from scratch.)

Please show a link to the exercise or a screenshot. That seems like a ridiculous exercise and I'd like to see it for myself.

There are quite a few things wrong.

To get 3 numbers printed in the inner loop, the range(1, 3) should be range(3), because ranges stop before the end value. This will yield 0, 1, 2.
To get the numbers to decrease, you can subtract j from the maximum value, or you could use a reverse range range(3, 0, -1). I've used the first method below.
There's no need to include str(i) in the output, you should just print 3-j.
The special case that if should check is the last value to be printed on the line, not the first. Other elements are printed with end='' so it won't go to the next line.
end=' ' should be end='' because we already put a space when we concatenated ", ".

for i in range(1, 3):
    for j in range(3):
        if j != 2:
            print(str(3-j) + ", ", end="")
        else:
            print(str(3-j))


This code does produce the required result but, deviates from the original code
for i in range(1, 3):
  for j in range(3, 0, -1):
    if j != 1:
      print(j, end=', ')
    else:
      print(j)

